# How to data bind to a list of objects with knockout?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Here is my view model.

Server side:

```
public class ShoppingListModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ItemModel> Items{ get; set; }

    public ShoppingListModel()
    {
        Items=new List<ItemModel>();
    }
}
```

On the client side, I use `knockout.mapping`.

```
ShoppingListModel = function(data) {
    var vm = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
    return vm;
};
```

To bind the server-side model to the client-side model:

```
@{
    var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
    var data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, jsonSerializerSettings));
}

@section scripts {
<script src="~/App/ShoppingListModel.js"></script>

    <script>    
        var vm = ShoppingListModel(@Html.Raw(data));
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    </script>
}
```

The code above:

1. use `JSON.NET` to serialize the server-side `Model` into a camel cased json.
2. build the client-side view model.
3. ko.applyBinding()

Now I want to take advantage of the two-way binding.

First I tested on the `Name`:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name, new { @data_bind="value:name"})
<input type="text" data-bind="value:name"/>
```

It went well, I was able to edit the `Name` value on a text `input` and persist the value into the hidden `input`. The updated value could reach the POST action when the form is submitted.

Now the question: how to implement the binding on the list?

My test is to remove one item from the 'Items' list:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Items, new { data_bind = "value: items" })

<tbody data-bind="foreach:items">
    <tr>
        <td>

            <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
        </td>
        <td><span data-bind="text:count"></span></td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-xs" data-bind="click:$parent.remove">
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

A `console.log()` tells me that the client-side model has been updated, but this time, the binding on the `HiddenFor` has never worked! When the form is submitted, `Items` is always null.

I guess it is reasonable because in Html:

```
<input type="hidden" value="xxx" />
```

we are expecting the value of an input to be a simple value.

I was thinking about loop through the list and data-bind from there. But it is also difficult. The knockout `foreach` is on `tbody` tag while a C# `foreach` is placed around `tr` (inside `tbody`).

Then what is the correct way to bind the list?

---

Here is my solution based on Fabio's suggestion:

1. In the client-side ko model,

add a computed value to bind the list into a json string.

```
vm.itemsJson = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.toJSON(vm.items);
},this);
```

2. In the html view,

add a hidden input to hold the json string and post with our form.

```
<input name="itemsjson" type="hidden" data-bind="value:itemsJson"/>
```

3. In the server side view model,

besides

```
public List<ItemModel> Items{ get; set; }
```

Add another string property to hold the posted json.

```
public string ItemsJson { get; set; }
```

At this point, we are able to see the `ItemsJson` value successfully sent to the controller action.

4. Parse the json string to the List on the server side.

Since it is typed model, we are to use `JSON.Net` to deserialize.

```
var items=JArray.Parse(model.ItemsJson);

model.Items = items.
    Select(i => new ItemModel {Name = (string) i["name"], Count = (int) i["count"]})
    .ToList();
return View(model);
```

Be sure to use `JArray.Parse()` for a `List` instead of `JObject.Parse()`.

It works.

Let's see if there is any better way than manually parsing json string. Otherwise, I would mark Fabio's answer as our solution after this weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use computed observables to bind the hidden field, like this:

```
function YourViewModel() {
     var self = this;
     self.items = ko.observableArray(); //fill it with your stuff;
     self.valueForHiddenField = ko.computed(function() {
         return ko.toJSON(self.items);
     }, this); //use this observable as value of your hidden field
}
```

For more information http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html

EDIT 1

You don't need to convert the json inside your controller. Instead sending a json to your server, send the collection using list of hidden fields. Like this:

```
<form>
   <!-- ko foreach: items -->
       <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: property1, attr: { name: 'Items[' + $index() + '].Property1' }">
        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: property2, attr: { name: 'Items[' + $index() + '].Property2' }">
   <!-- /ko -->

</form>
```

Then you can send the post, and don't need to worry about the collection, it will refresh automatically when you changed the items observableArray.

Comment: Nice suggestion. So when the json value in the hidden input is POSTed to the server, that Json value will be automatically parsed into a List, I guess? Let me try and confirm it.

Comment: Unfortunately no. the json in the hidden input is a string and won't get parsed into the server side model automatically. Need some way for model binding on the server side.

Comment: I've made it work with manual json parsing. Posted the whole thing at the bottom of question. Wondering if there is more elegant way. A big "thank you".

Comment: I edited my answer, now you can post your collection in a more elegant way. Hope it helps.